# how to handle loaded PouchDB data in ionic 2 and see them in PouchDB inspector

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, pouchdb

I want to build some sort of offline app with some json data, i want fill my database when app's life cycle is first loading. i used pouchDb in ionic 2, i added PouchDB load plugin and its work fine with this code:

```
let PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-load'));


initDB() {

    this._db = new PouchDB('cities3', { adapter: 'websql' }); 
    this._db.load('../../../assessts/cities.json').then(function () {

        console.log("Done loading!");
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("error while loading!")

    });
```

the output will be **Done loading!** but when i want to check the data in PouchDB inspector i will get this error:

```
No PouchDB found

To use the current page with PouchDB-Fauxton, window.PouchDB needs to be set.
```

i know that i should use **window["PouchDB"] = PouchDB;** but my question is, **where**?

Comment: At the very root of your application I would do: `window.PouchDB = require('pouchdb')`. Although it should work anywhere as long as `window.PouchDB` is initialized before you open the inspector.

Comment: Or `window.PouchDB = PouchDB`

Answer (score 0):

You should add it after 
`this._db = new PouchDB('cities3', { adapter: 'websql' });`